# Why is the standard deviation bias correction factor called c₄?

Tags: mathematics, notation, statistics

The [term to remove bias from an estimate of standard deviation for a normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation#Results_for_the_normal_distribution) is referred to as $c_4$.

What is the origin or reason for using that notation for the correction factor?

Comment: Relevant: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/466014/8030